# Wordpress category page redirects in .htaccess not working

Tags: categories, redirect, htaccess, wp-redirect

Wordpress automatically generates category pages, for example:
https://planthardware.com/category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/

I want to redirect this to a custom page, for example:
https://planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/

What's the simplest way to do this?

I tried this (I suspect this is overcomplicated):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/(.*) https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And if I want to do multiple does something like the following make sense? Or is there redundancy and I don't need to turn RewriteEngine on for each redirect?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/(.*) https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/microgreens/growing/(.*) https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-growing/$1 [R=301,L]

etc...
```

This code is currently not working on my site. I've cleared my wordpress cache, and I'm running Ezoic, I've also cleared my Ezoic cache.

I've also tried putting the following in .htaccess and it doesn't work:

```
RedirectPermanent https://www.planthardware.com/category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/ https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where in your `.htaccess` file are you adding these directives? You appear to be trying to  match something at the end of the URL (and passing this through to the target) - but this is not stated in your example?

Comment: My htaccess was empty before attempting this so these are the first and only lines. 
Website was never redirected from another domain or anything like that in the past.
I'm not trying to do anything fancy, just one url to another url.

Comment: "My htaccess was empty" - Where are the WordPress directives? Are you using Apache?

Comment: I'm using Nginx I think. I don't know what a Wordpress directive is. The only lines in the .htaccess file are the lines above. It was empty (0 Bytes) before I tried to add redirects.

Comment: On Apache you need a `.htaccess` file (or similar directives in the main server config) in order to implement pretty permalinks, as you seem to be using here. Without this you'll just get a 404. It's possible the necessary directives are implemented in the server config, in which case `.htaccess` might be disabled - which could explain why nothing is working. Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I'm not sure which file is the server config. I'm hosted on Bluehost and can access the cPanel and see a lot of files. A search for nginx.conf or apache.conf doesn't return anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this your own dedicated server?

Comment: I don't think so. I'm using basic Bluehost hosting on the order of $5 or $10/month something like that, it shouldn't be dedicated hosting at that price right?

Comment: You're likely on a _shared_ host, in which case you won't have access to the server config. So, where is the WordPress `.htaccess` file? Are you sure this isn't just _hidden_?

Comment: There's a cPanel I can log into. I enabled show dotfiles and I can see the .htaccess file.

Comment: So which `.htaccess` file have _you_ been editing?

Comment: There's only one .htaccess file that I'm aware of. It's in the bottom directory in cPanel. I've been editing that one.

Comment: "I enabled show dotfiles and I can see the .htaccess file." - So this is the `.htaccess` file you have been editing all this time - and it is empty? When you say "bottom directory" - do you mean document root (eg. "public_html" or "htdocs")? Try putting any _nonsense_ at the top of the file - you should get an error if `.htaccess` overrides are enabled.

Comment: Yes just the one file. 
Adding some jibberish "worked". Trying to access https://planthardware.com/category/microgreens/business-microgreens/
Gives me this in the browser: Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@planthardware.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
...

Comment: Right, except that going to the document root, ie. `https://planthardware.com/` - is not producing the same error? So this would seem to be reading another file?

Comment: The .htaccess file is located in /home2/ivingwd5 (same folder as public_html, public_ftp and everything else). It was an empty file before I tried adding these redirects.

Comment: It does seem to give the same error at https://planthardware.com/

Comment: It needs to be in the `public_html` directory itself. I don't see the error when requesting the root - maybe I'm seeing a cached response

Comment: Oh bingo I think you just solved it. There's another .htaccess file in public_htm and it's not empty. It has some wordpress redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have found the right `.htaccess` file in the document root (ie. inside the `public_html` directory) then these redirect directives need to go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing WordPress directives. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` or `RewriteBase` directives. (The `RewriteBase` directive is not actually being used here anyway.) The `RewriteEngine On` directive appears later in the file (inside the WordPress block), you do not need to repeat this.

To redirect as required you just need the following:

```
RewriteRule ^category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/ https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/ [R=301,L]
```

You do not need the capturing subpattern `(.*)` and corresponding `$1` backreference to redirect the example URL as stated.

NB: Test with 302 (temporary) redirect first to avoid potential caching issues.

If you are redirecting to the same scheme and hostname, you do not need to repeat these in the target URL. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/ /microgreens-equipment/ [R=301,L]
```

You can use capturing subpatterns and backreferences to avoid repetition. For  example:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(microgreens)/recommended-(equipment)/ /$1-$2/ [R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference contains "microgreens" from the first capturing group (parenthesised subpattern) and `$2` contains "equipment" from the second.

---

**UPDATE:** And for the second redirect you could write it like this (using backreferences):

```
RewriteRule ^category/(microgreens)/(growing)/ /$1-$2/ [R=301,L]
```

To redirect to `/microgreens-growing/`.

---

*Aside*:

> I've also tried putting the following in .htaccess and it doesn't work:
>
> ```
> RedirectPermanent https://www.planthardware.com/category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/ https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/
> ```

Note that the `RedirectPermanent` directive belongs to mod_alias (as opposed to mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`), consequently it runs much later, after all the other mod_rewrite directives, despite the apparent order of the directives in the config file. For this reason, it is advisable not to mix redirects from both modules, since you can get unexpected conflicts.

Note that the `RedirectPermanent` directive matches against the root relative URL-path (starting with a slash), not the absolute URL. So, the above directive wouldn't match anyway. It should be written like this instead:

```
RedirectPermanent /category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/ https://www.planthardware.com/microgreens-equipment/
```

OR (omitting the scheme + hostname on the target URL):

```
RedirectPermanent /category/microgreens/recommended-equipment/ /microgreens-equipment/
```

Comment: Thanks MrWhite.

Comment: @Turillian You're welcome. I've updated my answer with a bit more information.

Comment: Now if only Bluehost tools didn't just go down so I could implement this... heh